# asp.net ajax call type post directing to options

Tags: asp.net-ajax

Is there any specific request format for asp.NET ajax call?
While using type as post its redirecting it to options saying 404 not found.

AJAX call code

```
$.ajax({
 type: 'GET',
 url: 'http://salesmeet2014.syntel.in/CallService.aspx?MethodName=Getall&callback=?',
 contentType: "application/x-javascript",
 crossDomain: true,
 data: "{}",
 dataType: 'jsonp',
 success: function(json) {
   console.log(json);

},
error: function(e) {
   console.log(e.message);
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

Comment out the `datatype:'jsonp'`. The marking the datatype as JSONP is not necessary and it will overwrite the method post to options.